# Google map not dragging smoothly

Tags: android, google-maps

I want map smooth as like [MAPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps) app do in android phone. I don't know why my app's map not working smoothly. I'll try below code

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

and here is onMapReady() code

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(false);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

You can see [my app performance](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1uoptxif7s1txe/my_map_app.mp4?dl=0) & [default app performance](https://www.dropbox.com/s/slk8azrzm5u7fw5/google_map_app.mp4?dl=0). If there is missing something please help me.

Comment: Google map in the background having catching and downloading feature for render map. Thats why google map faster.

Comment: Any solution that makes little bit faster? Because of ola and uber app little bit faster than my app.

Comment: They all are having a tie-up with Google I thinks that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mMap.animateCamera(...)` instead of `mMap.moveCamera(...)`